# IntelliJ debug configuration for Perl script

Tags: perl, debugging, intellij-idea

I am new user of IntelliJ IDE. I was successfully able to set the run/debug configuartions for my Jave programs by choosing

> New Configuration->Application->Specifying Java Main class and the
>   Program args

But I have some Perl scripts in my application and was wondering how to do that. I don't see an option for adding a new configuration for perl scripts.

Any help of how to do this or explanation on why it cant be done would be much helpful

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

IntelliJ does not support perl

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/wishlist/show?pr=&wid=368

Which is a pity

Comment: Seems like it does now. See the other answer

Answer (score 6):

It does now: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796
debugging is now supported too the same way as in other languages

Comment: it has a plugin that enabling perl support https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796-perl